# CSS - Cross-browser inner border with border-radius for images

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, cross-browser

I have an absolutely positioned image (the size is responsively determined using `max-width`) to which I want to add an **inner** border. Because it's an image, I can neither use pseudo elements (as `img` elements don't have them), nor `box-shadow` (because the shadow renders behind the image, not on top).

So the method I am using is an `outline` in combination with `outline-offset`. This works for most browsers I have tested. However I ran into a problem on iOS/Safari, where the corners of the outline get cut off instead of being rounded.

iOS:

[image: iOS]

Other browsers:

[image: Other browsers]

Consider this example:

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: 4px solid red;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

```html
The following example works in most browsers, but not iOS Safari and perhaps some other browsers.

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg">
</div>
```

I probably also won't be able to wrap the image in another element, due to the absolute positioning and responsive sizing. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix the issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This problem only occurs in older versions of Safari or older browsers in general. However, it should be compatible with those browsers as well.

Comment: This works on iOS Safari for me. What version of iOS are you using? Also, why not just use border and `box-sizing: border-box;` instead of outline?

Comment: @davidleininger Tested on iOS 15.6.1 (should work on older versions/devices as well). The reason I want to cover the image with the border is because in my production code the border has a transparency, which I left out from the example for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: iOS 15.6.1 was released in August 2022. In November 2022, Apple [released an update to Safari Technical Preview](https://webkit.org/blog/13575/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-157/) that fixed the outlines so they follow the border radius. Your version of iOS doesn't support it.

Comment: @davidleininger Thank you for finding this. So I guess if I can't find an alternative to using an outline, at least I know this will be less of a problem in the future or something that won't affect many users.

Comment: Considering the version of iOS that your on is almost a year old, I would agree.